# Scroll View and Tableview programmatically alignment

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, cgrectmake

I am implementing a `UIScrollView` which holds some user data. I am downloading additional data from my server. Once downloaded the `contentSize` of my `UIScrollView` should be the original size + the number of cells times their height.

All the `UIViews` are aligned and set programmatically.

The `UITableView` is the lowest and is **supposed to always stretch to the bottom of the screen.**

In my **viewDidLayoutSubviews** I set the following

```
    groupsCountLbl.frame = CGRectMake(groupsLbl.frame.maxX + 5,
    seperatorLbl.frame.maxY + 15 , 40, 20)
    groupsCountLbl.sizeToFit()

    table.frame = CGRectMake(0, groupsCountLbl.frame.maxY + 10,
    bounds.width, bounds.height - groupsCountLbl.frame.maxY + 10)

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(bounds.width, bounds.height
     + self.table.frame.height)
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
```

Rather than filling the whole view it appears like this:
[image]

Comment: does your app support AutoLayout?

Comment: Yes it is supporting AutoLayout. For example the cells are aligned with autoLayout

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your UIScrollView bounds to superview

```
NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
  "V:|-[scrollview]-|",
  options: [],
  metrics: nil,
  views: ["scrollview": scrollview])

NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
  "H:|-[scrollview]-|",
  options: [],
  metrics: nil,
  views: ["scrollview": scrollview])
```

*Let me know in the comment if you have some problems*

Comment: What exactly is this doing? Never worked with NSLayoutConstraints. Also: Do I need to turn of Autolayout in the Storyboard? I am using auto layout to align the cell.contentView though.

Comment: If you have the possibility to set your scrollview constraint in the xib you can avoid my code and set top, bottom, trailing and leading to 0 relative to superview...basically I think your problems is the frame of your scrollview which should be equal to bounds of superview

Comment: now i set the scrollView and the contentView to the same size going (0,0,0,0) I still got the samt problem though I tested whether they are equal heights. I am calling the resizing method of the table view in my ServerRequest btw.

Comment: I am now trying to implement a whole new concept using tableView and a tableViewHeader as recommended by other users here.